# Access Update a table row based on a combo box selection

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

I have a table I would like to edit based on a combo box selection in a form.

For example, let's say I have a table that has the following fields:

Computer Name | Location | Number of Updates installed | etc.

What I have done is created a form based on this table. It includes a combo box to select the computer name that's being updated. What I would like to do is fill out the rows based on the computer selected in the combo box.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'fill out' - find an existing record and display it? Or create a new record? A field titled "Number of Updates Installed" sounds like you want aggregate data (possibly a count). If this is a calculated field, this is what aggregate queries are for. Or build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calculations.

Comment: My vision for the form is to first select the computer they're going to be working on from the combo box. Each computer has its own row in the actual table. When they select the IP address of the computer in the combo box, every bit of information they fill out in the tracker will only apply to that computer. The number of updates is just a number field, they'll enter how many total updates they installed when checking for updates, for example.

Comment: Then this is just normal data entry? Can each computer have more than one 'tracker' record? If so, there should be a table of computers and then a table for the 'tracker' records.

Comment: It is just data entry. Each computer only has one tracker and all of the information entered in the tracker will fill in corresponding rows on the table. I just don't know how to only change the information for the item that's selected in the combobox.

Comment: If you want the combobox to serve as search criteria to find existing record, it must be UNBOUND. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. Otherwise, make sure you are on a new record row and just enter data.

Comment: I don't want it as search criteria. I want to bind the editing of table fields based on the combo box selection.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You have a table of computer info and you want to locate a record in that table to edit info? Then your options are to use intrinsic search tools (from ribbon and right click menu) on the bound combobox or use unbound combobox to select search criteria and code (VBA or macro) to locate record.

Comment: I don't want to locate the record. I want to fill out the table based on what's selected in the combobox.

For instance, let's say I have a combobox that has the following items:

Bob's Computer
Mike's Computer
Jimbo's Computer

If I select Bob's Computer from the combobox, I want the fields in the form to edit the fields in the table for Bob's Computer.

Comment: But you have to find the record first. Unless you want to use UNBOUND form and UNBOUND controls to input values and VBA runs UPDATE action SQL. Or you are entering data into ANOTHER table, make sure you are on a New Record row. Then code can populate fields. However, should not save all that related info because that is duplicating data.

Comment: I only want to change one table. This is also a web form/table, so the options are limited. The fields I want to edit are already bound to the table.

Comment: If this is a form bound to the table you want to edit and the controls are bound to fields, then you need to first find existing record because anything entered into the controls will edit record or if on New Record row, create a new record. Options to locate record already described. Except can use macro instead of VBA.